Retrieving data from another worksheet Lock Sheets with password
I have made a VBA code to extract data from another worksheet and paste on my current workbook/sheet where the Macro Button was implemented. I am trying to insert a line of code to lock the spreadsheet with password for the spreadsheet I'm extracting but cant seem to do so with ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOS" . Why is that so?
> Option Explicit Sub Pull_Data_January() Application.ScreenUpdating =
> False
>     Dim objExcel2 As Object, arr As Variant
>     Set objExcel2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
>     ' open the source workbook and select the source sheet
>     With objExcel2.Workbooks.Open("C:Desktop\Personal File\Personal Files & Forms\January")
>         ' copy the source range to variant array
>         arr = .Worksheets("January").Range("E5:AJ43").Value
>         ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="SOS"
>         ' close the source workbook
>         .Close savechanges:=False
>     End With
>     ' select current workbook and paste the values
>     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("January").Range("E5:AJ43").Resize(UBound(arr,
> 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
>     ' close the source application instance
>     objExcel2.Quit
>     Set objExcel2 = Nothing
>     ActiveWorkbook.Save
>     MsgBox "Update Completed! " End Sub

Tried inserting the lock sheet code in the middle of the line while copying the data value but i cant seem to do so.
